# Python Selenium Chrome Driver version 123.0.6312.86

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, conda, virtualenv

Previously I installed Chrome driver version 103.0.5060.53 on the conda virtual environment but now Chrome is updated with the newer Version 123.0.6312.86 so the script is not working I want to update new stable Chrome driver version 123.0.6312.86.

Can anyone please guide me, How I can install the new Chrome driver version on my virtual environment?

I am getting the following errors:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 103
Current browser version is 123.0.6312.86 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3):

https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/
Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 0.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download new ChromeDriver for you OS from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads). It should be the same version as an installed Chrome.
2. Replace old ChromeDriver file in your project with the new one.